# How to modify code to turn page list into clickable links?

Tags: wordpress, list, linked-list

I have the following code to show sibling pages and their thumbnails in the sidebar. How would I modify this to make the title include the hyperlink?

```
<?php global $post; //not neccessary if used in the loop
$parent = $post->post_parent; 
if( $parent ) :
    $siblings = get_pages( 'child_of=' . $parent . '&parent=' . $parent . '&exclude=' 
. $post->ID);
    if( $siblings ) foreach( $siblings as $sibling ) :
        //start of whatever you need to output//
        echo $sibling->post_title;
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($sibling->ID,'medium');
        //end of whatever you need to output//
    endforeach;
endif; //ends if( $parent ) //
?>
```

Comment: Have you try anything ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php global $post; //not neccessary if used in the loop
$parent = $post->post_parent; 
if( $parent ) :
    $siblings = get_pages( 'child_of=' . $parent . '&parent=' . $parent . '&exclude=' 
. $post->ID);
    if( $siblings ) foreach( $siblings as $sibling ) :
        //start of whatever you need to output//
        echo '<a href="'. get_page_link( $sibling ->ID ) . '">' . $sibling->post_title. '</a>';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($sibling->ID,'medium');
        //end of whatever you need to output//
    endforeach;
endif; //ends if( $parent ) //
?>
```

Αlthough it's an easy question and with a little search you would find your answer yourself